# angularjs обновление $rootscope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть два шаблона. В одном мы отображаем данные, в другом редактируем.
Работаем с одним `$rootScope`. Вся сложность в том, что переменная не меняется, а содержимое - меняется. Например `$rootScope.profile.image = 'users/01/avatar.jpg'` `$rootScope.profile.image` всегда для этого пользователя будет именно таким, но изображение по ссылке может меняется не ограниченное количество раз. Погуглил, но не нашел работающего для меня решение обновить содержимое `$rootScope`. Как это исправить?

Comment: Приведите ваш код для отображения и редактирования данных.

Comment: как отследить изменение $rootScope?

Comment: Без примера вашего кода, мы ничего не можем сказать. Еще лучше, если вы приведете [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно у вас проблема не в $rootScope. Если вы говорите, что переменная *$rootScope.profile.image* не меняется то что вы хотите обновить?
Если у вас изменилось изображение по ссылке (что не очень хорошая практика), то вам нужно его заново скачать в том месте, где вы используете эту ссылку.
Это можно организовать, изменив ссылку следующим образом:

```
$rootScope.profile.image = 'users/01/avatar.jpg?v=' + Date.now()
```